# iFrames - how do search engines read them?

Tags: ajax, iframe, seo, search-engine

I know that search engines base part of the calculation of rankings on how many other sites point to a specific site, so I was just wondering, given the following situation:

- http://siteA/page.aspx contains an iFrame.
- This iFrame points to http://siteB/script.aspx?url=http://siteA/page.aspx.
- http://siteB/script.aspx generates a list of 1 or more links based on the supplied URL.
- http://siteA/page.aspx therefore displays a list of links.

1) Where would Google etc consider links to be based?

2) If it would consider the links to be based at siteB, is there another technique I could use to force search engines to read the links as being based at siteA? For example ajax.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you're looking to build a link farm Google will block you faster than you can blink. I would seriously reconsider using iframes to links as in the situation you've described you've no reason to load another page on your first.

To answer your question, iframes load a page on another, so naturally Google will view them as separate entities.

Comment: I have checked other sources and have received the same answer. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

ok think I may have the answer - http://www.highrankings.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=44155&st=0&gopid=312999&#entry312999

Comment: Link needs you  to sign in :(

Comment: No you don't - I just went there and viewed it fine whilst being logged out. At the bottom it says 1 user is viewing this thread, and in the detail it says 0 members, 1 guest (me). Please remove the downvote if that was you.

Comment: I never edited it - have a look at the edit! All I changed was the capital O on Ok to lower case knowing that I would have to edit it for you to remove the downvote..